# QML QtQuick.Controls 2.2 ScrollView - how to disable horizontal flicking?

Tags: android, qml, scrollview, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to disable only horizontal flicking (with having only vertical scrolling and flicking of content) when using QtQuick.Controls 2.2 ScrollView which I declare like:

```
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
}
```

I've tried

```
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff

    Flickable.flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
}
```

but Android app is crashing silently.

How do get disable only horizontal flicking and scrolling but having vertical ones working?

Answer (score 4):

Just specify [ScrollView::contentWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#contentWidth-prop).

> This property holds the width of the scrollable content.
>
> If only a single item is used within a ScrollView, the content size is
>   automatically calculated based on the implicit size of its contained
>   item.

```
ScrollView {
    contentWidth: -1
    anchors.fill: parent

    Text {
        text: "ABC"
        font.pixelSize: 512
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried, but it just displays "ABC" without vertical flicking and scrolling (I've copied Text 10 times to get what to scroll vertically). I thought it is obvious that i want to disable only horizontal flicking but have vertical scrolling and flicking. I should clarify my question.

Comment: Actually, I have used ListView instead, but I am still curious about this way

Comment: The text element is just dummy example content. If the content high enough, you have vertical scrolling. The point of the example is to show how to disable horizontal scrolling as you requested. What comes to ListView, a vertical ListView does not have horizontal scrolling by default. You must have explicitly overridden the content width to make it horizontally scrollable.

Comment: I did duplicate Text {...} 10 times, so it was pretty big content to scroll, but it not worked, I've checked.

Comment: Actually, I've wrapped 10 Text {} by ColumnLayout in order to have single pretty long child of ScrollView. In this way content looks as expected - longer that scroll view, but is still not scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

```
ScrollView {
        id: svId
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: textId.width
        Text {
            id: textId
            width: svId.width    //Can't use parent.width
            text: "this is a long text"
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView does have a property called availableWidth. In the Qt documentation is written,

> If you want the ScrollView to only scroll vertically, you can bind contentWidth to availableWidth (and vice versa for contentHeight). This will let the contents fill out all the available space horizontally inside the ScrollView, taking any padding or scroll bars into account.

So you only need to set the contentWidth of the ScrollView to availableWidth and you are done.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#details